# Is there a way to set the Floating-Point Unit's rounding mode in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

I want to know how to round a floating-point number to a machine floating number(for example *double*).
The number "0.01111116" cannot be represented by machine floating point, in some rounding mode, this number should be represented as "0.011111159999999995" with some precision loss.
But I don't know how to finish this in Java?
So I want to know the API to set the rounding mode to get the exact representation of machine floating-point number in Java.
Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify just what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: like the function "fesetround" in the C language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a literal `0.01111116` in the source code of your program, the Java compiler converts that into the binary floating point representation at compile time.

If you are talking about (say) a String containing the characters "0.01111116", that gets converted to a binary floating point representation if/when you call (*for example*) `Double.parseDouble(...)`.

Either way, the conversion happens behind the scenes and you don't have any control over the actual rounding.  But in a sense it is moot.  It is inherent in the nature of the representation that some rounding happens, and the result is generally speaking "the most accurate" you can get from a mathematical perspective ... given the floating point type you have chosen.

If you really wanted the conversion to use different rounding / truncation rules you could either do this after the fact (e.g. round or truncate the converted value), or you could implement your own String to floating-point conversion method.

You won't be able to change the way that the Java compiler converts literals.  It is part of the language specification.

---

> So I want to know the API to set the rounding mode to get the exact representation of machine floating-point number in Java.

There is another way of thinking about this.

The exact representation of a machine floating point number is 32 or 64 bits of binary data.  You could render the bits of a `double` as hexadecimal in a couple of ways:

- `Double::doubleToLongBits` or `Double::doubleToRawLongBits` followed by `Long::toHexString` gives a precise but unhelpful rendering, or
- `Double::toHexString` gives a hexadecimal floating point representation.

All of these renderings are exact (no rounding errors) representations of the `double`, but most readers won't understand them.  (The "raw" version deals best with edge-cases involving variant NaN values.)

There are equivalent methods for `float`.

Comment: The problem I am concerned is that there are two floating point variable d1 and d2; (for example d1 = 0.1; d2 = 0.2); and d1 + d2 should be equal to 0.3 in mathematical semantic. But in the floating point semantic, the rounding mode exists and 0.3 cannot be exact represented by floating-point type. So the result is near to 0.3, but the result could be 0.2999***... or 0.3000***...; So I want to know how to set the rounding mode or how to get the result with specific rounding direction.

Comment: @gingeredder - there is no solution using floating point.  If you need precise control of rounding, don't use floating point at all.  Do your arithmetic using `BigDecimal` and don't convert to `float` or `double`.  `BigDecimal` does give you more control over rounding, etc, but more importantly it is base-10 based, so any number in finite decimal notation (i.e. without a recurring part) can be represented exactly.

Answer (score 6):

The [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) does not provide any means to control the floating-point rounding mode. Round-to-nearest is used.

It is not generally possible to arrange for floating-point arithmetic to produce mathematically exact results, so software must be designed to tolerate and adjust for errors or, in very special cases, to get exact results by using extra care.

Answer (score -1):

Try commons-math3 Precision http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Precision.html

```
    double d = 0.1 + 0.2;
    System.out.println(d);
    d = Precision.round(d, 1);  <-- 1 decimal place
    System.out.println(d);
```

output

```
0.30000000000000004
0.3
```

Comment: In the C language, there is a function "fesetround" to set the current rounding mode. In java, I want to do the similar thing. So I want to know the similar function in java to set the current rounding direction.

Comment: The problem I am concerned is that there are two floating point variable d1 and d2; (for example d1 = 0.1; d2 = 0.2); and d1 + d2 should be equal to 0.3 in mathematical semantic. But in the floating point semantic, the rounding mode exists and 0.3 cannot be exactly represented by floating-point type. So the result is near to 0.3, but the result could be 0.2999***... or 0.3000***...; So I want to know how to set the rounding mode or how to get the result with specific rounding direction